Flutter: border side inside a Grid
I'm trying to display a division operation:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.significados.com%2Fdivision%2F&psig=AOvVaw1oTeLhuIZdSezZfHiIUjoY&ust=1719054725905000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBEQjRxqFwoTCJDc84bI7IYDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE
For that, I'm using Grid widget and inside, a Container->Card (this will contain each number later on).
The logic is fine, but I'm facing some problems with the division line.
My first idea was something like this:
Widget gridCard(int index) {
    return Container(
      decoration: index > 3 && index < 7
          ? BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                left: index == 4
                    ? const BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 5,
                      )
                    : BorderSide.none,
                bottom: const BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 5,
                ),
              ),
            )
          : null,
      child: Card(),
    );
  }

The problem with this is that I was not applying any border for the rest of the cards, so the one with it, looks different:

To make all the same, I tried this:
Widget gridCard(int index) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          left: BorderSide(
            color: index == 3 ? Colors.black : Colors.transparent,
            width: 5,
          ),
          bottom: BorderSide(
            color: index > 2 && index < 7 ? Colors.black : Colors.transparent,
            width: 5,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Card(),
    );
  }

But now, the border is not a straight line when we have another border, and the line doesn't look right:


I can live with option A, but would be possible to fix it somehow?

Try below code, in which I have made 3 grid methods, apply them on your grid. Hope it helps
Simple grid = 0,1,2,8...
Widget gridCard(int index) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          left: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            width: 5,
          ),
          bottom: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            width: 5,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Card(),
    );
  }

grid = 3
Widget gridCard3(int index) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          left: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 5,
          ),
          bottom: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 5,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Card(),
    );

grid = 4,5,6,7
Widget gridCardUnder4567(int index) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Align(
        child: Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green,
            border: Border(
              left: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                width: 0,
              ),
              bottom: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.black,
                width: 5,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: Card(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


None of these widgets fix the problem. You are applying the border to all the elements. Please, read again my question

Please refer to the generated output for the answered code - https://i.imgur.com/Hp4yJNX.png

ah sorry, I didn't understand your solution then, I thought you were proposing 3 options.
How to calculate the last container size dynamically? The operation length can be different each time

I thought that the size of the operation is always the same, although you can use the answer methods depending on your need with your specific condition.

fair enough, I didn't mention that. I guess I could take the parent widget size anyway
